# Create only some module in a maven profile doesn't work by <module> tag

Tags: maven, profile, multi-module

I have a Maven multi module project. in a specific profile named "release" I defined only some modules.

```
 <modules>
        <module>media</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>web</module>
</modules>
```

but when I build and active release profile, all module target will create. why ? and how to solve it ?

Comment: You should never use modules within a profile..What do you need that? What is the problem you are trying to solve...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
    <!--<modules>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>-->

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>CustomProfile</id>
            <modules>
                <module>dao</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>dao</module>
                <module>web</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] dao ................................................ SUCCESS [  1.213 s]
[INFO] MyCustomProject .................................... SUCCESS [  0.016 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.394 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-31T13:42:44+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use Apache Maven 3.5.2

Comment: what is your maven version ?

Comment: I use Apache Maven 3.5.2, I added a build summary with custom pofile (with only one module)

Comment: I tested with the last version of maven, but still it's not working. for all module, creates target directory and artifact file.

Comment: How do you build? What is your build script? Did you disable default profile?

Comment: I use intelij idea maven integration plugin. no, I just select the profile that I want. How can I disable default profile ? @rodgenk

Comment: First, try this: mvn clean install -P CustomProfile. In IDEA you should switch off default profile and switch on custom. If it doesn't work, you should check your pom configuration.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your help. I check the command that execute by IDE plugin. everything OK. clean package -P release,!default-profile. is my pom conf wrong ? I can't find any example about it in Maven official site.

Comment: You are welcome! :) Yes, it looks like something wrong with the configuration. It's not the frequent case - using profiles within modules.